# Unattended rsync and remote command

Tags: ssh

I am trying to write a script that compiles an executable, runs `rsync` to copy it to a remote server, and then opens an `ssh` session into the server and dispatches the executable to the grid engine.

In other words, I want a script that does the following:

```
1. (locally) compile
2. rsync local to remote
3. (remotely) run command to dispatch
```

The issue I have is that compiling the executable takes a lot of time, and right now my simple bash script will first compile, then prompt my password for the rsync and again for the SSH command.

Is there a way to somehow prompt my password once, prior to the compilation step? We are not allowed to use SSH keys for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use `sshpass`:

```
read -s -p "Password: " SSHPASS
# compile
rsync -e "sshpass -e ssh" ...
sshpass -e ssh <foo> rm -rf /
```

Arguably worse security than using keys.